# Joomla Slider which takes data from custom forms

Tags: joomla, slider, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I’m a newbie to Joomla and I want to add an image slider to my Joomla site.

When user click on an image in the joomla page, it should redirect to the backend web application (which is a JSP/Servlet webapp running in tomcat) with several parameters specific to that image. These parameters need to store in joomla along with the images.

1)  I have to create a custom form in Joomla to upload an image and other parameters. But also I have to display the already entered records and allow user to edit/delete them.

2)  These uploaded images should display in the image slider with their parameters.

Can anyone advise how should I approach this?

Comment: I have some progress on this.. I created a grid with component-creator [link](http://www.component-creator.com/). And now trying to create a module for slider by reading data from DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created it my own way. Hope this helps to somebody.

I created a component of a grid with a form using [component-creator](http://www.component-creator.com/en/). This is a free tool which is very useful in Joomla component generating. ( Or you can be a paid user for advanced features)

Then I installed the component and upload images with their parameters.
Then I created a custom module for image carousel. Details for these images were taken from the mysql database. I used [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) for the image slider.

Thanx :)